# Ubuntu problem with external monitor resolution greater than 1920x1080

Tags: 22.04, display, intel-graphics, display-resolution, external-monitor

**I have a Dell i7 iRis xe Graphics notebook with Ubuntu 22.04 and I can't put a resolution higher than 1920x1080 on the external monitor**

> I have searched the entire forum, apart from using chatgpt to see if
> it could give me an alternative, but I could not solve my problem.

I have a Gigabyte monitor that accepts a resolution of up to 2560 px x 1440 px and a frequency of up to 165 Hz.
Resolution type QHD

I have a notebook also very similar to this one that is a Dell Inspirion i5 iRIS xe and I put it on the Gigabyte monitor and the 2560x1440 resolution works and it even gives me an option of 3440x1440

**I tried:**

```
Install ubuntu 22.10 update kernel.
Install ubuntu 20.04 update kernel, update it to 22.04.
Install ubuntu 22.04 upgrade kernel
Install graphics manually
```

**None of the above options worked for me.**

**try the following**

```
cvt 2560 1440 60
cvt --reduced 2560 1440 60
cvt 2560 1440 33
```

I couldn't get some of these resolutions to take effect either, the only time this had some effect and left my monitor with a black screen and a message like signal out of range is with ubuntu 20.04 with the following command:

```
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_33.00" 162.75 2560 2696 2960 3360 1440 1443 1448 1470 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 2560x1440_33.00
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 2560x1440_33.00
```

In ubuntu 22.04 i have the following in xrandr

```
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
    1920x1080 59.96*+
    1440x1080 59.99
    1400x1050 59.98
    1280x1024 59.89
    1280x960 59.94
    1152x864 59.96
    1024x768 59.92
    800x600 59.86
    640x480 59.38
    320x240 59.52
    1680x1050 59.95
    1440x900 59.89
    1280x800 59.81
    720x480 59.71
    640x400 59.95
    320x200 58.96
    1600x900 59.95
    1368x768 59.88
    1280x720 59.86
    1024x576 59.90
    864x486 59.92
    720x400 59.55
    640x350 59.77
XWAYLAND1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
    1920x1080 59.96*+
    1440x1080 59.99
    1400x1050 59.98
    1280x1024 59.89
    1280x960 59.94
    1152x864 59.96
    1024x768 59.92
    800x600 59.86
    640x480 59.38
    320x240 59.52
    1680x1050 59.95
    1440x900 59.89
    1280x800 59.81
    720x480 59.71
    640x400 59.95
    320x200 58.96
    1600x900 59.95
    1368x768 59.88
    1280x720 59.86
    1024x576 59.90
    864x486 59.92
    720x400 59.55
    640x350 59.77
```

**If I try to perform the option of:**

```
cvt 2560 1440 60
# 2560x1440 59.96Hz (CVT 3.69M9) hsync: 89.52kHz; pclk: 312.25 MHz
Modeline "2560x1440_60.00" 312.25 2560 2752 3024 3488 1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
```

**then i put**

```
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00" 312.25 2560 2752 3024 3488 1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
```

**then**

```
xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND1 2560x1440_60.00
I also tried with
xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND1 "2560x1440_60.00"
```

**and finally**

```
xrandr --output XWAYLAND1 --mode 2560x1440_60.00

X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
   Major opcode of failed request: 139 (RANDR)
   Minor opcode of failed request: 21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
   Value in failed request: 0x0
   Serial number of failed request: 29
   Current serial number in output stream: 29
```

**This would be my current graphics driver**

```
sudo lshw -C display

*-display                 
       descripción: VGA compatible controller
       producto: TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       id físico: 2
       información del bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
       nombre lógico: /dev/fb0
       versión: 01
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuración: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 resolution=1920,1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       recursos: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:157 memoria:6002000000-6002ffffff memoria:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memoria:c0000-dffff memoria:4010000000-4016ffffff memoria:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

**A little more information from get-edid**

```
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
Problem requesting slave address: Device or resource busy
No EDID on bus 1
No EDID on bus 2
No EDID on bus 3
No EDID on bus 5
No EDID on bus 6
No EDID on bus 7
No EDID on bus 8
No EDID on bus 9
No EDID on bus 10
No EDID on bus 11
2 potential busses found: 4 12
Will scan through until the first EDID is found.
Pass a bus number as an option to this program to go only for that one.
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "G27QC A"
    ModelName "G27QC A"
    VendorName "GBT"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 50 of 2021
    # EDID version 1.3
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 600 340
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "true"
    Horizsync 30-222
    VertRefresh 48-144
    # Maximum pixel clock is 600MHz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1920x1080, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x720, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x960, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1440x900, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1680x1050, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x720, 120Hz

    #Extension block found. Parsing...
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 75)
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 76)
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 63)
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 64)
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 96)
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 97)
    Modeline    "Mode 13" 497.75 2560 2608 2640 2720 1440 1443 1448 1525 +hsync -vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 0" 241.50 2560 2608 2640 2720 1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync +vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 1" 592.25 2560 2581 2613 2666 1440 1443 1448 1543 +hsync +vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 2" 25.200 640 656 752 800 480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 3" 27.027 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 4" 27.027 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 5" 27.000 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 6" 27.000 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 7" 74.250 1280 1720 1760 1980 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 8" 148.500 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 9" 148.500 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 10" 74.250 1280 1390 1420 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 11" 74.250 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1082 1087 1125 +hsync +vsync interlace
    Modeline    "Mode 12" 74.250 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1082 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync interlace
    Modeline    "Mode 14" 325.08 1920 1944 1976 2056 1080 1083 1088 1098 +hsync +vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 15" 285.50 1920 1968 2000 2080 1080 1083 1088 1144 +hsync -vsync 
    Option "PreferredMode" "Mode 13"
EndSection
256-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 4
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
```

**lspci -vnn | grep -i "VGA|3D"**

```
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] [8086:9a49] (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

As I mentioned before, I have lowered the frequency, and many more tests, I don't know what the problem that my notebook does not detect is the monitor resolution.

**PS: I don't want to change OS, all my life I use Ubuntu to program and all my production environments I have with Ubuntu Server**

Comment: You have a graphics issue and in all this ton of info I do not see the Graphics card info or the driver you are using for it. Please use edit and add this info.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @David, I already included the drivers

Comment: Have you considered using xorg rather than wayland session? Logout and hit the cog icon to switch to Ubuntu on Xorg. Does it work then?

Comment: @popey I managed to change to Xorg, the good thing is that now eDP1 and HDMI1 appear, I tried to do the whole process but it didn't work for me either, it happens exactly as I explain with ubuntu 20.04 it's like it tries to take the new resolution but it throws an error
`xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed`

Try to create cvt 2560 1440 33 and that causes the external monitor to go black screen with the phrase out of range.
Try again with cvt --reduced 2560 1440 and it doesn't work either